# Logging interactive input and output without capturing all typed input and control characters

Tags: terminal, logs, readline, tee, units

I am trying to log output from an interactive command-line program; [`units`](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/), specifically.

I have tried using `tee`  like this:

```
units | tee units.log
```

or script like this:

```
script -c units units.log
```

but they both log all the backspaces and tab completions as special characters like this:

```
You have: 55 horsepower ^G/^H^[[K^M
You want: wat^Gt ^M
    * 41013.493^M
    / 2.438222e-05^M
```

The manpage for `script` mentions this issue.

> **BUGS**
>
> Script places everything in the log file, including linefeeds and backspaces.
>   This is not what the naive user expects.

I am aware of the work-around with viewing the file using `cat` and `more` or stripping the escape characters with `col` as  mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152339/format-output-from-unix-script-command-remove-backspaces-linefeeds-and-delet

As well as the perl script here:

http://log.guidoderosa.net/2009/05/another-old-post-which-may-be-useful.html

But I don't especially want to fix an existing log file: I want to avoid creating new log files garbled with deleted input and control characters.

I thought I had fixed the problem using `rlwrap`, but it conflicts with the `units` readline functionality, so that it either fails to capture the output, or with `rlwrap -a` it captures the output but negates the ability of `units` to use tab-completion. `rlwrap -a -N` does not help. This is well-documented in the man page:

> **BUGS and LIMITATIONS**
>
> Though  it  is  flexible, delivers the goods (readline functionality), and
>   adheres to the Unix "many small tools" paradigm, rlwrap  is a kludge. It
>   cannot know anything about command's internal state, which makes
>   context-sensitive completion impossible. Using the readline  library  from
>   within command is still the best option.

Is there any way to cleanly log interactive input and output that doesn't mess with the existing `readline` functionality?

Update: I would be happy with something like

```
units | col -b | tee units.log
```

but that hangs while waiting for interactive input. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure? I initially tried this with `tee (GNU coreutils) 8.13` and `GNU Units version 1.87` on Ubuntu 12.04, and have since verified it with `units 2.02` and the latest version of `gnu coreutils` from the git repository.

Comment: How did you determine that there were no control characters in the text file?

Comment: I take that back, I do indeed have the control chars. Must have done something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Units recently added this feature in version 2.10.

> The `--log` option allows you to save the results of calculations in a file; this can be useful if you need a permanent record of your work.

https://www.gnu.org/software/units/manual/units.html#Logging-Calculations